# SD card with STM32 in memory-mapped mode

Tags: stm32, spi, flash, ltdc

I need an external flash in STM32H743 MCU and it must work in memory-mapped mode (it's necessary for LTDC display controller). Can I use SD card instead of usual flash chip in this case?
It will be connected to qspi controller like single spi flash memory.

Comment: Do you know how you will configure the QSPI controller in your STM32 to send the SD-card commands?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use SD card instead of usual flash chip in this case?

No. SD cards are not well suited to memory-mapping in general, as they do not have predictable access times and cannot be read/written on a more granular basis than a sector (512 bytes).

> It will be connected to qspi controller like single spi flash memory.

That won't work. The QSPI controller is not a general-purpose SPI peripheral; it can only be used for devices which conform to a particular serial flash protocol. SD cards are not such a device.

If your image data does not fit into main memory, consider adding SDRAM to your device and loading the image from SD at startup.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use an SD card instead of usual flash chip in this case?

Maybe. It depends on what type of data you are dealing with. You most likely won't be able to display video, but displaying images should be possible.

> Can it be connected to QSPI controller like SPI flash memory?

No. Although SD cards do support SPI as a fallback interface, it will be painfully slow, and you would have to implement the protocol manually. Take a look at the SD Association's [Physical Layer Simplified Specification](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/index.html) if you're not convinced.

---

### Solution

Fortunately, the [STM32H753](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/c9/a3/76/fa/55/46/45/fa/DM00314099/files/DM00314099.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00314099.pdf) comes with an SDMMC interface, which is designed specifically to communicate with SD cards, supports multiple modes (including UHS-I), and handles some of the protocol overhead in hardware.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

It may be theoretically possible if you were to design an interface chip which does SDIO to QSPI. Access times will be awful though.

So find something else.

Eg: Copy all the data from the SD card to a large QSPI flash first.